# Button color not changing on macOS in Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to change the color of QPushButton to QPalette::Accent, but the color does not change.

At first I tried to do it this way:

```
 QPushButton button("Apply");
 QPalette palette = QPalette();
 palette.setColor(QPalette::Button, palette.color(QPalette::Accent));
 button.setPalette(palette);
 button.setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

But I only got this:

[image: button1]

When I tried to use stylesheet I got a button that lost its macOS style

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("open");
 button->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,0);");
```

[image: button2]

But I want to achieve this result:

[image: button3]

I apologize for the stupid question, but I have already searched the entire Internet, and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blue button in MacOS, like in your example "button3", indicates that this is a default button. So, e.g. pressing Enter will press this button.

To achieve the same behavior (and look), you should simply call `button.setDefault(true)`. This might be restricted to dialog windows.

Coloring the button blue without making it the default button would mislead the user.

Comment: I knew it was a stupid question). Thank you so much for your help, and sorry for wasting your time. I just spent my whole life on Windows, and only a few weeks ago I switched to Mac for the first time.

Comment: I don't believe it is a stupid question, in fact I gave the question an upvote and I do not answer stupid questions.